# C# : Access file of previous verion of clickonce in latest version

Tags: c#, deployment, clickonce

I am using clickonce technology to deploy the .net windows application. For some reason i need to change the approach of saving one of the XML file. Currently this XML file is getting saved in the install folder of the click once application itself. 
It is a kind of user preference XML file which contain some value so that user don't need to type that value again and again.

Problem i am having is that whenever there is an update on the click once , new install folder is created on user machine and that preference XML file will get reset.  So now i am changing the approach and saving this value in the Documents folder. But i want to access the value present in the  file from earlier  version of click once and  copy it into documents folder (new location). This will ensure there is no disruption to the user in the way they use the tool.

This is a production scenario. I have tried but could not find a way how to do it. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Click once doesnt offer you such an option. I suggest, you do this manually by adding a few lines of code in your Main-Method

Comment: I have written a code in Main method but it refer to the current application start up path.. Is there a way to access the previous version application startup path. If that is doable then i guess this can be worked upon.

Comment: Not directly. You probably have to loop through all directories in your `Application Files` folder.